# How to delete file/folder on Dropbox using REST or IdHTTP Firemonkey (Rad Studio 10 Seattle) – Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, dropbox, firemonkey

I'm trying to delete file or folder on Dropbox. I have tried with REST:

```
OAuth2Authenticator.AccessToken := Settings.DropBoxToken;
RESTRequest.Method := TRestRequestMethod.rmDelete;
RESTClient.BaseURL := 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/'
RESTRequest.Resource := '/MyFolder/File_test.txt';
RESTRequest.Execute;
```

And I have also tried using idHTTP:

```
IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ' + Settings.DropBoxToken;
IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';

IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['root'] := 'dropbox';
IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['path'] := '/MyFolder/File_test.txt';

DropBoxURL = 'https://api.dropbox.com/1/fileops/delete';
IdHTTP.Delete(DropBoxURL);  //I have aslo tried   IdHTTP.Post(DropBoxURL, TStream(nil));
```

I got the error:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request  or HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

I can upload and download the data without any problems but I can't delete files. The solution must work on Firemonkey (Rad Studio 10 Seattle) – Android/iOS.

Hope someone can help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox API v1 is only RESTish. It is not a fully RESTful API. That means that some REST patterns don't apply. For example, the API v1 /delete endpoint expects a POST method, per the documentation:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#fileops-delete

Your REST version uses the `DELETE` method instead though. It also seems to be missing the `/delete/` portion of the endpoint.

Your idHTTP version also uses what the `Delete` method, which should be `Post`. You mentioned you tried that also, but it seems you ran in to a different issue. Make sure you read the full response body, as it may contain a more useful error message.

Also, note that Dropbox API v1 is deprecated:

https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/

You should switch to Dropbox API v2:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help.

I have investigated the response body and have successfully deleted the files on DropBox.

Here is the code which works on Windows and Android:

```
DropBoxURL := 'https://api.dropbox.com/2/files/delete';

IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ' + Settings.DropBoxToken;
IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json; charset=utf-8';

JsonToSend := TStringStream.Create('{"path": "' + sSyncFolder + '"}', TEncoding.UTF8);
Try
    Memo1.lines.add(IdHTTP1.Post(DropBoxURL, JsonToSend));
except on e: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
begin
    memo1.lines.add(idHTTP1.response.ResponseText);
    memo1.lines.add(e.ErrorMessage);
end;
```